# access a javascript function in the same 'returned value object'

Tags: javascript

How do I access a javascript function in the same 'returned value object' and the parent function is unnamed.

here's a code sample

```
function ($http, $rootScope, $timeout, $location, config, $q, sessionService) {

    return {
        _get_user_approval_mode: function (data) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            this.prepareHttpCall($http, true);
            $http.post(config.CLIENT_API_ROOT + 'user-approval-mode', {
                    params: data
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    defer.resolve(response);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    if (error_handler(error) === "") { //Getting on this line since error_handler() is undefined
                        defer.reject(error);
                    }
                });
            return defer.promise;
        },
        error_handler(error) {
            console.log('error received in handler');
            console.log(error);
            if (error.status == "400") {
                $('#somethingWrong').modal('show');
                $rootScope.errorHandleMessage = error.data.reason;
            } else if (error.status == "401" && error.data.message == "Unauthorized" || error.status == "401" && error.data.message == "The incoming token has expired") {
                // $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                // $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                $location.path('/login');
            } else if (error.status + "".match('5\d{2}')) {
                $('#somethingWrong').modal('show');
                $rootScope.errorHandleMessage = "Sorry! something went wrong, please try after sometime.";
            } else {
                return "";
            }
            return "error handled";
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting error of undefined in function '_get_user_approval_mode' when try calling 'error_handler' function - as commented in the above code.

Comment: That code sample ins’t even valid JavaScript, `error_handler(error) {` makes no sense at this point, should presumably be `error_handler: function(error) {` as well. But that will of course not solve your problem - the only place where these functions have a name, is in the context of the object you return here.

Comment: @misorude: ES2015 introduced method syntax for object literals.

Comment: @FelixKling ah, wasn’t aware of that. (But then I would at least expect people to decide on one syntax or the other, but not use both in parallel.)

Comment: @misorude: I have to agree there :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how `_get_user_approval_mode` is called (i.e. without knowing what its `this` value will be), the "safest" solution is to assign the object to a variable and access that variable:

```
function ($http, $rootScope, $timeout, $location, config, $q, sessionService) {

    var obj = {
        _get_user_approval_mode: function (data) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            this.prepareHttpCall($http, true);
            $http.post(config.CLIENT_API_ROOT + 'user-approval-mode', {
                    params: data
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    defer.resolve(response);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    if (obj.error_handler(error) === "") {
                        defer.reject(error);
                    }
                });
            return defer.promise;
        },
        error_handler(error) {
            // ...
        }
    };

    return obj;

}
```

However, if `error_handler` doesn't actually have to be a method on the object because it is not called from other code, defining it as a separate function would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks Felix - It worked and also your comment is correct - I should have thought that. Realy Appreciate your help - thanks